# How to locate unreferenced image in Aperture?

Tags: apple-aperture

I'm [importing my Aperture library into an Aperture library on an external drive](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/20079).

The issue is that I have some files which can't find their master (or reference? I'm still not sure of Aperture's verbiage). They all have the icon in the lower right corner:

[image: icon example]

But I'm not sure how to make that go away / connect it back to the original image. When I right click and go to "Locate Referenced Files" I can't navigate into the Aperture drive on my computer, where I know the file is.

How do I re-merge the library so those files are properly updated? Or just show it were the file is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tell Apple Aperture to store ALL files by reference?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/27547/how-to-tell-apple-aperture-to-store-all-files-by-reference)

Comment: The thing is I don't want it to be referenced (I think). I want it to pull that file over to the external drive.

Answer (score 1):

From an [answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/27593/75526) to [How to tell Apple Aperture to store ALL files by reference?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/27547/75526)

> For existing photos already in the monolithic library bundle, perhaps the "Relocate Original" command would be of assistance? You could move the original images to a new location, but keep the reference within Aperture.
>
> [image: relocate original]